# CORS Error - Why do I have CORS issues when I require some libraries as multer or fs with nodejs and express?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am working on an application that let the user send a document from its computer to the app server. Just to let you know, the main aim is to extract some text/json elements server side to send to a database.

The frontend is made with React.js, the backend with node.js.

When I try to send a pdf, I sometimes encounter CORS and preflight CORS errors if I require "multer" or "fs".

In the configuration below, I am able to send my POST request ONLY if `const multer=require("multer")` is quoted (`//`). If I try to require multer I receive the following errors :

> [XHR] OPTIONS https://api.mysite.fr/gettextfrompdf CORS Missing Allow
> Origin
>
> Blocage d’une requête multiorigines (Cross-Origin Request) : la
> politique « Same Origin » ne permet pas de consulter la ressource
> distante située sur https://api.mysite.fr/gettextfrompdf. Raison :
> l’en-tête CORS « Access-Control-Allow-Origin » est manquant. Code
> d’état : 500.

Here is my frontend :

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function MyApp() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [rdyToSend, setRdyToSend] = useState(false);
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState();
  const [isFilePicked, setIsFilePicked] = useState(false);
  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false);


  const changeHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.files[0]);
    setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
    setIsSelected(true);
  };

  const handleRdyToSend = () => {
    console.log(selectedFile);
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("fileToUpload", selectedFile, "sample.pdf");
    for (var key of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(key[0] + ", " + key[1]);
    }
    console.log(formData);
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers:
        "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com",
      origin:
        "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com",
      body: JSON.stringify({

        fileToUpload: formData,
      }),
      headers: {
        mode: "cors",
        origin:
          "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com",
      },
    };
    fetch("https://api.mysite.fr/gettextfrompdf", requestOptions)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result);
          console.log(result);
        },

        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
    setRdyToSend(true);
  };

  if (!rdyToSend) {
    //form
    return (
      <div className="submitForm">
        <form>
          <label>
            Déposer ici votre document PDF :
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" onChange={changeHandler} />
            {isSelected ? (
              <div>
                <p>Filename: {selectedFile.name}</p>
                <p>Filetype: {selectedFile.type}</p>
                <p>Size in bytes: {selectedFile.size}</p>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <p> Please select a file !</p>
            )}
          </label>
          <input type="button" value="Envoyer" onClick={handleRdyToSend} />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    if (error) {
      return <div>Erreur : {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Chargement...</div>;
    } else {
      console.log(items);
      return (
        <div>
          Request done !<div>Texte : {items.text}</div>
          <div>{items.sentFromClient}</div> */}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

And there is my backend :

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const multer = require("multer"); //This is the lib that causes my CORS errors

const normalizePort = (val) => {
  const port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    return val;
  }
  if (port >= 0) {
    return port;
  }
  return false;
};
const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || 4200);

const path = require("path");
var cors = require("cors");
app.options("*", cors());

app.use(cors());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const allowedOrigins = [
"origin1",
"origin2",
"etc..."
  ];
  const original = req.headers.origin;
  if (allowedOrigins.includes(original)) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", original);
    cors({
      origin: original,
      credentials: true,
    });
  }
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  // res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");

  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
  );

  next();
});

app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

app.use(express.json({ type: "*/*" }));

app.post("/gettextfrompdf", function (req, res) {
  //Here I send a response from server that I receive when multer is quoted...
});
```

I also have that situation if I require("fs").

I also tried to Enables preflight CORS according to this https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Any help would be great, thanks !

Comment: Why do you `require("multer")` if you don't use it in your code?

Comment: I need it to store the document in the database. I have just hided the part inside app.post("/gettextfrompdf", function (req, res) {

Comment: CORS triggers different requirements based on the content-type of the http request.  So, if you're using different content-types, that may require pre-flight.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What if it is only about pdf and images ?

Comment: Still not working, only when I require multer... Any suggestion ?